# C printf. Is this valid code?

Tags: c

The following code outputs 14 using gcc. Why?

```
printf("%d", (int*)2+3); // This code is meant to be obfuscated!
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int *` casts `2` as an address. Adding `3` will add `3*sizeof(int)` to it. On your system it seems tha `sizeof(int)` is equal to `4` and that's why it is giving `2 + 12 = 14`.

But, you should note that the given code invokes **undefined behavior** for two reasons:

1. Performing arithmetic on a pointer that doesn't point to an array element causes undefined behavior.
2. #### 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: Actually, it is undefined behaviour because that pointer is not a pointer to an array element.

Comment: since it is not dereferencing the element, I think it is fine

Comment: @JohnSmith: gnasher alludes to the fact that pointer-arithmetic is only defined on pointers pointing to elements of the same array. Also, passing a pointer to a variadic function and pretending it's a number is UB all by itself, too.

Comment: +1 for not giving the typical and boring *Undefined Behavior* answer, but rather just explaining OP the output of his/her code.

Comment: @barakmanos: -1 for not even mentioning that is UB and instead pretending all is well.

Comment: @Deduplicator: 1. haccks actually mentions that `"%p"` should be used instead of `"%d"`. 2. How can you give me a -1 here???

Comment: -1 for the reasons stated above. You can't claim that this is all fine and dandy just because you don't dereference the pointer.

Comment: @barakmanos: Just informing you that you missed the most important fact about the answer, which merits a -1 all by itself, and cannot be healed even by explaining in excruciating detail what happens in a specific implementation. Also, that's only one of the two sources of UB (in addition, we have implementation-defined behavior, but that's tame in comparison).

Comment: @haccks: Well, and I don't know why I have to say this _again_, you're wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: OP's extremely basic question implies that he or she are interested in a practical explanation rather than "UB". UB is great. People here are quoting it all the time. But it is not very constructive, especially when it comes to newbies asking questions here, which some people (with you amongst them) don't seem to understand. Of course, I cannot tell for sure whether or not OP is a newbie, but the question at hand implies that he or she are indeed under that category.

Comment: @barakmanos: So you mean "just ignore UB when writing code in the real world"? That indicates that you do not understand what UB is. Have a little read of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx).

Comment: @barakmanos: OP wants to know what happens, and that's fine. But pretending his example-code is ok is doing him and any other reader a severe disservice. If haccks had mentioned all the reasons of UB and ID in addition to mentioning what exactly happens in one specific implementation with this specific example (OS+compiler+libraries+options+specific_versions+anything_else_relevant), it would be fine. This way, it's simply wrong.

Comment: @haccks: It's worth noting that on a 64-bit system, OP would be using `"%d"` in order to print an 8-byte variable, which would most certainly lead to printing "a weird value" (i.e., "only part" of the actual value). Also, it's worth mentioning the effect that the underlying HW architecture (big-endian vs. little-endian) would have on the output in such case.

Comment: **Oh good and now the OP's accepted this _wrong_ and _misleading_ answer. You've succeeded in spreading more misinformation and dangerous anti-knowledge to yet another programmer. I hope you're pleased with yourself, @haccks.**

Comment: I'm partly with Barak Manos. But the implementation-defined and undefined aspects of the question should be pointed out, and a good answer would also try to shed some light on why the standard made such things undefined/implementation-defined -- behaviour isn't undefined just because it is undefined, the standard committee makes it such/leaves it as such for a reason. Platforms crashing with wrongly aligned pointers, segmented memory, a debugging implementation with bounds-checking, and optimization opportunities (I don't see any here, but it's a common reason for UB) come to mind...

Comment: @mafso: Thank you for your support. With combined forces we can defeat the dark side and prevail.

Comment: @mafso: I think you are doing both me and Lightness a disservice here. We are specifically not against pointing out what may happen in some real-world implementations some of the time, but against pretending invalid code is valid, and also against omitting some of the reasons it is invalid. Doing the first might make for interesting bed-time reading, but the second is absolutely vital for reliable programs.

Comment: @barakmanos: You might want to read again and try to understand our point.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why not viceversa?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; And finally you win! **My apologies to all for providing a bit misleading answer**. Now corrected that. I ignored the fact that pointer arithmetic can't be done on pointer that doesn't point to an array element. "**I hope you're pleased with yourself, @haccks.**': Of course not. This was not intentional and I hope you can understand. Anyone can do mistakes (its human nature).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As it currently stands, the answer is perfectly fine. You should remove the downvote now. :)

Comment: @Sofffia: He removed the misinformation but now he's just making unsubstantiated assertions. In short, `[citation needed]`. For an example of how to do that, see my answer.

Comment: @gnasher729; You are right. Sorry for ignoring the fact.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; " For an example of how to do that, see my answer.": Isn't that a sarcasm?

Comment: @haccks Yeah, he is not being very constructive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "now he's just making unsubstantiated assertions" -- How so? You are proving his assertions in your answer. We don't need duplicated quotes.

Comment: @Sofffia: Yes, _I'm_ substantiating them in _my_ answer. He's not in his answer. You don't get an upvote for an answer because it is completed by another answer. And an answer that says "see this other answer for the answer" is not an answer: it is a link.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'd written this comment before I read Lightness's answer (which also explains, why 14 is the output on some platforms, including OP's). And I thought I was clear enough, that I think the UB should be pointed out (I see no "disservice"). I just liked the attempt to explain the output, this is where I support Barak's comments, and didn't upvote this answer because it was incomplete, and didn't leave a comment, because others already did.

Comment: @mafso: Written text is deficient in nuance, and I might have been to sensitive there. It happens.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here.

First is that your expression `(int*)2+3` results in undefined behaviour, because [almost certainly] there is no valid array at `0x2` that expands out to `0xE` (14):

> `[C99: 6.5.6/8]:` When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. **If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.** In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.** If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

The second is that you're using the `%d` formatting specifier but providing an object of pointer type:

> `[C99: 7.19.6.1/9]:` If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Either one of these factors is enough to say that your program has no meaningful output whatsoever. However, if you do see "14" it's because `(int*)2` results in a pointer to memory at `0x2`, and applying pointer arithmetic `+3` despite the undefined behaviour *may* add a further `sizeof(int)*3` to the pointer. `0x2 + 4*3` → `0x2 + 12` → `0xE` (14). The problem is that printing this pointer value through `%d` could even be a security vulnerability on a system where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)`.

If you didn't give this answer in your interview, you should not have the job; if you didn't give this answer in your interview but you got the job, you shouldn't take the job.

Comment: I am late to the party however where in the OPs code does the pointer ever get evaluated? I see a cast and array arithmetic but the pointer itself is never evaluated.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: If it's not evaluated, how could its value be printed out? How could arithmetic be performed on it? If you meant "dereferenced" then the answer is (a) it's not dereferenced, and (b) that does not matter. See _all the text in my answer_ to find out why. It's baffling to me that so few people seem to be aware that you do not need to dereference an invalid pointer in order to have undefined behaviour in your program - merely _obtaining_ one is usually enough. This is really basic C, guys. Please tell me you're not working on any systems that I have to use? Please?

Comment: First off the sizeof and %d/%p are obvious concerns. I revised my question in the comment (right after I posted it) clarifying where is the **pointer** being evaluated. Evaluation of a pointer would imply dereferencing it. Pointer arithmetic doesn't involve actually evaluating p itself. Printing out a pointers value (assume the printf was correct) still doesn't entail evaluating the pointer itself. However at any point the pointer IS evaluated then everything you say is true.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: _"Evaluation of a pointer would imply dereferencing it."_ What?? That's total hogwash! Where did you hear that? As for the rest of your comment, I've already addressed your fantasy that a dereference is required for UB to be invoked. Did you not _read_ the passages I cited in my answer? They're very clear.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That additional sentence is needed because it introduces one additional thing which is forbidden. But it is irrelevant for the example under discussion.

Comment: @MichaelPetch While producing and evaluating such a pointer is valid, dereferencing it is not. The last sentence simply highlights this fact. Deduplicator is right in that it's irrelevant for the code in question since it simply notes a restriction for pointers one past the last element of an array.

Comment: @Veritas : so since there is never any dereferencing going on and your comment suggests producing and evaluating such a pointer is valid do you believe this is legal and defined behavior (although output would be platform specific). Or do you believe it is legal and undefined?

Comment: @MichaelPetch. Undefined. Read the sentence again.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: So you're saying it's interesting that I didn't bold a sentence that is totally irrelevant to this question? Yeah, very interesting.

Comment: It is relevant in the sense that at no time was the pointer generated in the OPs code dereferenced (directly or indirectly) although that pointer may *point* at something that isn't valid once it is dereferenced and evaluated.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The last sentence is about pointers that point to one after the last element of an array. Do you notice any such pointer in the op's code?

Comment: Why do you keep going on about dereferences? This has nothing to do with dereferences. _Nothing_. I don't care how much you "do pointer arithmetic" - look at the quote from the standard. Just look at it. **Your. Pointer. Arithmetic. Has. Undefined. Behaviour.** I don't know how to make this any clearer for you.

Comment: In case the word "evaluation" is the source of your confusion, it is the act of evaluating the expression `(int*)2+3`, i.e. executing the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: My logic follows is that the offsetof macro is actually legal because at no point does the macro code dereference the pointer (it is used to generate a size value from it). If you can't do pointer arithmetic at address 2 you can't do pointer arithmetic at address 0 for the same reason (note the macro doesn't reference `NULL`). I will continue to argue that the problem of pointing at memory locations where data access may be invalid is not an issue unless what is pointed at is dereferenced. C99 also sues a similar macro

Comment: @MichaelPetch `offsetof` is defined by the C++ standard. The fact that it's defined in this particular way on your implementation is irrelevant with regards to C++ standard. This may mean that this environment provides stronger guarantees, but still - these guarantees are not provided by __C++ standard__. And were talking about C++ here.

Comment: _"the pointer itself is never evaluated to access the data it points to (which is what the last sentence in the quoted paragraph from the standard talks about)"_ No, that is called _dereferencing_. I've shown numerous times now that dereferencing has nothing to do with this. Unfortunately you don't seem to be listening to anyone! I just give up with you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : care to explain why the simple offsetof macro works and is considered defined behavior? And I ask this because I was asked if I program that does such casting to invalid memory locations. I do it on most platforms where I use the offsetof macro. So why are people not saying we shouldn't use this macro? What makes it different? If the OP has code that is undefined then the offsetof macro does as well. Offsetof fakes a data structure at a memory location that has no such object.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's a "possible implementation". What do you expect? As far as C++ goes, it's `#define offsetof(type, member) /*implementation-defined*/`, as seen on the cppreference site you posted link to.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your entire argument is based on wrong premise. Most C++ compilers do not define the `offsetof` macro that way. In particular, gcc does not define `offsetof` this way. Why? Because this implementation invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're misunderstanding what "undefined behaviour" is. This doesn't mean some action is erroneous. This simply means it's undefined. Some compilers may define certain behaviours. To check if your does, check the manual of your compiler. BUT, if your compiler does not say anything, you can't expect anything. The fact the macro is defined by C++ standard, is because otherwise, *there would be no portable way* to get the offset.

Comment: @MichaelPetch »Any other situations (that is, attempts to generate a pointer that isn't pointing at an element of the same array or one past the end) invoke undefined behavior.« from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). 
Implementations also have some more freedom e.g. GCC uses variadic templates in C++98 Mode, but that doesn’t mean you can do that too.

Comment: @milleniumbug : After reading 1 of your comments I realized why I was in error.Specifically I didn't take into account that there may be hardware architectures (which there are) that validate pointers (whether accessed or not) & that array arithmetic may produce undesired results if you go beyond an allocated region.Your point about the implementation of offsetof on certain compilers/hardware would be redefined to prevent using undefined behavior. It makes sense and I stand corrected. I don't currently write code that goes beyond what I allocate but if I did-I know what to look out for.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's invalid code, because we pass a integer pointer (int *) to 2nd param of printf and define an integer format (%d) in 1st param.

I don't have more knowledment in c but it's what i'm thinking.

Comment: That's certainly right as far as it goes, though Lightness Races in Orbit already mentioned that, as well as other errors, and what may happen sometimes with some implementations.